# What guarantees are there on interleaved reads and writes?

Tags: c++, iostream

When working with a C++ `std::iostream` (for example, `std::fstream` or `std::stringstream`, does the standard guarantee anything about the relationships between reads and writes performed on the same stream?  That is, is it necessarily true that if I write data into a `std::fstream`, then try reading data out of that stream, I should see the data I've written?  How about for a `std::stringstream`?  As an example, is this guaranteed to work?

```
std::stringstream myStream;
myStream << "137 Hello 2.71828";

int myInt;
std::string myString;
double myDouble;

myStream >> myInt >> myString >> myDouble; // Parse as expected?
```

Or what about this case?

```
std::fstream myStream("some-file.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
myStream << "137 Hello 2.71828";

int myInt;
std::string myString;
double myDouble;

myStream >> myInt >> myString >> myDouble; // Parse as expected?
```

I'm asking because I recently developed a networked stream class in which reads and writes do not affect one another (since reads pull from the network and writes send across the network).  That is, writing

```
myNetworkStream << "Hi there!" << endl;
```

writes across the network, while

```
myNetworkStream >> myValue;
```

reads from the network.  I'm not sure that this behavior is consistent with the general contract for streams.  If I had to guess, one of the following three probably holds:

1. The `iostream` contract says nothing about interleaved reads and writes, or
2. In general the `iostream` contract says nothing about interleaved reads and writes, but there are specific previsions in the spec governing how standard types like `fstream` and `stringstream` work, or
3. The `iostream` contract does say something about interleaved reads and writes that makes my network stream class violates.

I have a copy of the spec but the section on streams is so dense and cryptic it's all but impossible to follow.  If anyone could clarify exactly how `iostream`s are supposed to behave when you mix reads and writes, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: In your second case (with the "Parse as expected?" question, you won't get what you are expecting because the cursor is at the end of the stream.  In order to read in what you've written out, you'd have to reset the cursor to be beginning of the stream.

Comment: Additionally, reading right after writing on a bidirectional file stream, without flushing and/or seeking, will lead to undefined results, according to Langer/Kreft. (I haven't looked up the relevant clause in the standard.)

Comment: @Zac Howland- Iostreams have two cursors, a read cursor and a write cursor.  I was under the impression that these were independent of one another.  Are you use that you have to move the get pointer after writing?

Comment: See my answer. To my knowledge, there is no mainstream implementation of <iostream> that does *not* use the C standard library's functions as a basis.

Comment: There are 2 separate cursors.  However, unless you move one of them to someplace else, they are usually kept in sync with each other by default.  You can test that by printing out the value of `tellp` and `tellg` after you do your write operation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am not sure about the chapter and verse of the **C++** standard (which I don't have around to check), but I am very familiar with the **C** standard on the subject (which I *do* have around).

C99 states that a stream can be opened in read, write, or "update" mode. Only the latter mode allows both reading and writing to the same stream, but (quote):

> ...output shall not be directly followed by input without an
>   intervening call to the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`,
>   `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by output without an
>   intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters
>   end-of-file.

I would assume the C++ standard says something similar somewhere: You have to flush or reposition the stream before "reversing" on the read/write direction.

**Edit:** Indeed there are two seperate pointers - which can be queried with `basic_istream::tellg` and `basic_ostream::tellp`. However, I found mention of the possibility of the two *not* pointing at the same position in the stream only in connection with `stringstream`, not for `fstream`. Taken together with the above statement, it makes sense that way. Still cannot point you to chapter and verse of the standard, though, sorry.

Comment: This sounds normal, since writes and reads have typically different caches.

Comment: Actually, in my own implementation of a C library, reads and writes use the *same* cache, but interpret the indices differently. I guess this is what the standard committee had in mind - otherwise there would be additional bookkeeping and checking on each I/O access.

Comment: Yes, the C++ standard says the same thing about file-based streams by referring to the C standard: "The restrictions on reading and writing a sequence controlled by an object of class basic_filebuf<charT,traits> are the same as for reading and writing with the Standard C library FILEs."  Note though that the same restriction does not apply to stringstream.

Comment: Since stringstreams only exist as internal buffers (without an external representation that they might get out of sync with), there is no buffering-related restriction to be put on them. Hence, I would expect them to function properly even without intermediate repositioning. However, being the paranoid developer I am, I'd heavily `assert()` that assumption.

Comment: I believe the rationale here isn't so much the overhead for the consistency checks, but rather error reporting. If I used the streambuf for a write operation, and have uncommitted data in the buffer, a read operation that requires me to flush this data might return with an error from the flush operation, which I'd find very confusing from an API point of view.

Comment: @DevSolar- I just found a part of the C++ spec that supports this.  $27.8.1.1/3 says that file streams have their read and write pointers in lock-step a la C.  I still don't have definitive confirmation on `stringstream`, but this is still a great answer.